# How to allow manual folds with indent folds defined?

Tags: indentation, folding, manual-folding

I want to be allowed to create any folds at all, but I also want Vim to generate all the indent-based folds for me so that I can still use indent-based folding.

Is there some way to mix indent-based folding and manual folding to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think so. `:help fold-expr` is the method that gives you the most control so you could try to use it to a) mimic `:help fold-indent`, while b) allowing you to define arbitrary folds but well, that doesn't sound fun at all.